# how to check selected item in Check Box List (generated from code)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

i have I have an ASP.NET / VB application 
i need check on selected item in check box list but the checkbox is dynamically from code behind

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Selected_Items" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>
```

code behind 
page load

```
Dim CheckBoxList As New CheckBoxList
            pagerview.Controls.Add(CheckBoxList)
            ...est
```

Button1 Click event

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
Dim CheckBoxList1 As CheckBoxList = CType(Me.FindControl("CheckBoxList"), CheckBoxList)
Dim sCheckedValue As String = ""
For Each oItem As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
    If oItem.Selected Then
        If sCheckedValue = "" Then
            sCheckedValue = ("Selected Value : " + oItem.Value & " Selected Text: ") + oItem.Text
        Else
            sCheckedValue += ("<br/>Selected Value : " + oItem.Value & " Selected Text: ") + oItem.Text
        End If
    End If
Next
lbl_Selected_Items.Text = sCheckedValue
```

error text : null reference exception object reference not set to an instance of an object –
  [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzo0J.png)

Answer (score 0):

So what is happening? Error? no result?

At this point the only thing I can recommend is loading dynamic controls in the page init instead of the page load.

EDIT

You will find when you debug that your checkbox on the first line of your button click is Nothing. There are two mistakes in your code.

1. When you add the control to the form, you do not provide an id value. and you do not lookup this value
2. When you lookup the control in the button click FindControl only looks in a single container. It is not recursive. You should be calling pagerView.FindControl

The Page load (I still recommend init):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
Handles Me.Load
    Dim CheckBoxList As New CheckBoxList
    CheckBoxList.ID = "cbl1"
    pagerview.Controls.Add(CheckBoxList)
End Sub
```

And the button click:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim CheckBoxList1 As CheckBoxList = CType(pagerview.FindControl("cbl1"), CheckBoxList)
    Dim sCheckedValue As String = ""
    For Each oItem As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
        If oItem.Selected Then
            If sCheckedValue = "" Then
                sCheckedValue = ("Selected Value : " + oItem.Value & " Selected Text: ") + oItem.Text
            Else
                sCheckedValue += ("<br/>Selected Value : " + oItem.Value & " Selected Text: ") + oItem.Text
            End If
        End If
    Next
    lbl_Selected_Items.Text = sCheckedValue
End Sub
```

[MS Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you
the error is
null reference exception object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @MrSmith Such things have to be in comments, not in answers! Answer is the exact or possible solution, while your question or recommendation is a comment

Comment: @Khazratbek Thanks for making this clear. But the downvote, did you have a bad day buddy? Enjoy the answer.

Comment: @Ibrahim Alsurkhi Did this solve your problem? If so could you mark the answer?